# Web scraping with beautifulsoup: find and replace missing nodes with None

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, findall

I'm using the following code to scrape web items with Beaufulsoup:

```
item_id = []
items = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'item-id')
for one_item in items:
    list_item = one_item.text
    item_id.append(list_item)
```

However, some items are missing and when I run the code, I one get the list of the items available. How can I proceed to get the entire list including the missings listed as "None" ?

Comment: do you have a specific url ? i can attempt to code if you can provide or a dummy html

Comment: Here is the link. The elements I want to get are text in <div class="reference">. https://search.bvsalud.org/global-literature-on-novel-coronavirus-2019-ncov/?output=site&lang=en&from=0&sort=&format=summary&count=100&fb=&page=1&skfp=&index=tw&q=%28%22rapid+test%22+OR+%22rapid+diagnostic+test%22%29+AND+sensitivity+AND+specificity

Comment: Ok, i took a look it seems the issue is that the <div class="reference"> does not appear in each box that contains the text so it might be a better idea to use class_ = 'textArt' or something that is common. Then what you can do is check if class_=reference appears inside each box and then if it does not you set value as None and if it does you take the needed value. if this helps i can post it as an answer with more code.

Comment: I just posted the code, check that out. i believe that was the text you are trying to get and in some places where it is not there you want it as 'None' . Let me know if my answer helps or if there is something else you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
site_source = requests.get("https://search.bvsalud.org/global-literature-on-novel-coronavirus-2019-ncov/?output=site&lang=en&from=0&sort=&format=summary&count=100&fb=&page=1&skfp=&index=tw&q=%28%22rapid+test%22+OR+%22rapid+diagnostic+test%22%29+AND+sensitivity+AND+specificity").content
soup = bsoup(site_source, "html.parser")
item_list = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'textArt')
result_list = []
for item in item_list:
    result = item.find('div', class_='reference')
    if result is None:
        result_list.append('None')
    else:
        result_list.append(result.text)

for result in result_list:
    print(result)
```